Make parent elements on the same row of grid the same size?
I'm using WooCommerce for my e-commerce website (staging2.startrite-spares.co.uk). The category pages use a grid layout, with 3 thumbnails per grid.
Typically in WooCommerce function, the category tiles will all be the same height. If one of the three tiles on a row has a title on two lines, the other thumbnail titles on that row will take up the same amount of space.
However, I've changed the template of the category thumbnails to include a line underneath the title, that says how many products are in that category tile (called spare parts).
Now this line of text telling how many parts there are, is on a different line depending on how many lines of text the title has.
I managed to get a temporary fix by setting the category thumbnail parent to display: block; and setting a height value, but this doesn't look great if there is more space than needed. And when the title wraps on more than two lines on mobile, the title overlaps the 'x spare parts' text. The other problem with this temporary fix is when the title is only 1 line long, there is a big unnecessary gap. It only looks good on for with titles.
I've tried different display settings, but I feel like I may be missing out on something here. Can anyone point me in the right direction?
I've attached an image, you can see how the spare parts line is always in the same place due to the set height. If the title was long enough use 3 lines, it would obscure the spare parts count.

CSS for my temporary fix:
.product-category{
display:block;
margin-bottom: 0rem !important;
padding-bottom: 0em !important;
padding-left: 0.2rem !important;
padding-right: 0.2rem !important;

}

.woocommerce-loop-category__title {
box-sizing: border-box;
height: 2.5rem;
padding-bottom: 1.5rem !important;
margin-top: 0rem !important;
font-weight: bold !important;
}

I have removed most of the gaps in the grid columns to give the titles more space, an therefore make them less likely to wrap 3 lines.
Supposedly Subgrid is supposed to fix this, but I can't seem to have any luck with it so far.

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
